# Python raw input and system.split in a fab file

Tags: python, string-formatting, fabric

Python newbie here. Lets say I have this:

```
def test_servers():
        env.user = getpass.getuser()
        env.hosts = []
```

And I want to do something like this:

```
def test_servers():
            env.user = getpass.getuser()
            system = raw_input("Enter FQDN to show (seperated by commas for multiple entries)> ")
            env.hosts = system.split(',')
```

**??How do I make it populate as:**

```
env.hosts = ['firsthostinput', 'secondhostinput']
```

I'm still learning python and I'm not sure if system split can be combined with something else to do the format of what I want it to populate as. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**:

This is for my fab file. Just doing the system.split doesn't work. And because of a specific parameter "audit" I can't just pass hosts on the command line. They must be in input_servers().

So, this is what I have in my fabfile.py:

```
def input_servers():
    env.user = getpass.getuser()
    system = raw_input("Enter FQDN. User Commas to seperate multiple servers > "
    env.hosts = system.split(',')
```

This is what happens if I try to run it:

```
    [me@mothership fab_files]$ fab input_servers audit
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/fabric/main.py", line 654, in main
    docstring, callables, default = load_fabfile(fabfile)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/fabric/main.py", line 165, in load_fabfile
    imported = importer(os.path.splitext(fabfile)[0])
  File "/home/me/my-repo/stuff/fab_files/fabfile.py", line 17
    env.hosts = system.split(',')
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: What is your exact problem? `.split(',')` works on all strings, and `raw_input()` returns a string.

Comment: Is there actually something wrong with your code?  `split` did just what you wanted it to do on my machine.

Comment: Looks fine to me. You might also want to strip any leading/trailing whitespace with `env.hosts = map(str.strip, system.split(','))`

Comment: The problem is that I want to populate env.hosts with a list that matches ['firsthostinput', 'secondhostinput']. So, user inputs 3 words: apple, orange, pizza. I want the result to look EXACTLY like this: env.hosts = ['apple', 'orange', 'pizza']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> system  = raw_input("Enter FQDN to show (seperated by commas for multiple entries)
> ")
Enter FQDN to show (seperated by commas for multiple entries)> apple,oranges,lim
es,lemons
>>> system 
'apple,oranges,limes,lemons'
>>> splitted = system .split(',')
>>> splitted
['apple', 'oranges', 'limes', 'lemons']
```

not really sure what the problem here is?

Comment: It finally worked. Someone opened my fabfile to edit and never closed which caused a temp file to be created with different info in it. Thought I was going crazy. Thanks!